# $location.path not working first time with Ionic/Firebase

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building my first mobile app, using Ionic.io (version 1) and Firebase (latest version, 3 I believe) for the database. I am trying to set up the sign-up page such that, upon successful registration, the site redirects you to another page to fill in your profile. However, when I hit the signup button, although the user is successfully created, $location.path('...') does nothing (although 'Redirecting' does display in the console, see below). Upon a second click, it redirects the page as expected.

I tried several things, including introducing $scope.$apply, which went horribly wrong as I believe you can't use $scope inside a service/factory. I also tried appending a # at the front of the path. Using $location.url() doesn't help either. I managed to solve the problem by introducing a timeout, but this feels a bit hacky - why is this problem occurring and are there any better solutions?

Thanks!

Service:

```
signupEmail: function(newEmail, newPassword, newType) {
            var user;
                    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newEmail, newPassword)
                        //{email: newEmail,
                        //password: newPassword,}
                    .then(function(success) {
                        console.log("Successfully signed up!");
                        console.log(success);
              user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
              console.log("User....")
              console.log(user)
            }).then(function() {
              firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid).set({
                type: "..."
              })    
              console.log("Redirecting...");
              $timeout(function(){ 
                $location.path("/profile"); 
              },0);
            })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        console.log(error.code)
                        console.log(error.message)
                    })
                },
```

Controller:

```
function SignupCtrl($scope, AuthService) {
    $scope.data = {};

    $scope.createUser = function() {
        var newEmail = $scope.data.email;
        var newPassword = $scope.data.password;
        var newType = $scope.data.type;
        AuthService.signupEmail(newEmail, newPassword, newType)
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AuthService.signupEmail(newEmail, newPassword, newType)
 .then(function(_user) {
    $state.go('profile', _user )
 }, function(_error) {
    console.log(_error)
 });
```

have the service return the promise...

```
signupEmail: function(newEmail, newPassword, newType) {
     var user;

     return firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newEmail, newPassword)
          .then(function(success) {
              console.log("Successfully signed up!");
              console.log(success);
              user = firebase.auth().currentUser
              return user; 
           }).then(function(_user) {
               firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid).set({})
               return user;
           })
    },
```

Comment: It's working; thanks! However, I don't fully understand your code. Why are you introducing underscores (_user, _error)? Also, the function(_error) bit in the controller - instead I just copied over the .catch from the service and this seems to work just as well; are they equivalent or am I missing something?