# Angularjs ng-click redirects on seconds click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, firebase, angularjs-ng-click

Why does my ng-click redirects to a new location only on a second click?

It should be redirected to `$location.path('/login.signin');` however it only does so if I click again on the button. Strange. Where is this coming from?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="box-forgot" ng-controller="ResetPass">
    <form class="form-forgot" name="resetpassword">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                Reset Password:
            </legend>
            <p>
                Enter your new password below to reset the old password:
            </p>
            <div class="form-group">
                <span class="input-icon">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" ng-model="user.password" ng-minlength="8" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="">
                    <i class="fa fa-lock"></i> </span>
                <p class="help-block" ng-show="registration.password.$dirty && registration.password.$error.minlength">Too short! </p>

            </div>
            <div class="form-actions">
                <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-disabled="resetpassword.$invalid" ng-click="resetMe()">
                    Reset <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

and here is my controller:

```
app.controller("ResetPass", ["$scope","firebase", "$location",
    function ($scope,firebase, $location) {

    $scope.resetMe = function () {
        var newPassword = $scope.user.password;
        var actionCode = $location.search().oobCode;
        var mode = $location.search().mode;
        firebase.auth().confirmPasswordReset(actionCode, newPassword)
            .then(function (resp) {
            console.log("reset pass, done");
            $location.path('/login.signin');
        }).catch(function (error) {
            $scope.errMsg = true;
            $scope.errorMessage = error.message;
        });
    }

}]);
```

**Edit**: I can't figure out how to relate the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296778/location-path-not-working-first-time-with-ionic-firebase) to my problem.

**Edit 2**: For the ui router states, here's the [link](http://pastebin.com/ft8hYZyQ).

Comment: What are you seeing in your console?  Have you tried putting a breakpoint in your javascript to see if the resetMe is being fired?  Are you seeing the errMsg?  Also, you wired up your action on the button but you have a form with validation. Why not replace your `ng-click="resetMe()"` on the button to `ng-submit="resetMe()"` on the form and add `type="submit"` on your button. This will allow form validation to fire before your resetMe is called. It also lets you check if `$scope.resetpassword.$valid` is true.

Comment: it gets fired and i get the console messages. the redirect only fires on a second click.

Comment: You mean the you see `console.log("reset pass, done");` but `$location.path` doesn't execute?

Comment: yes, i see the message on the first click, and then I click again, then the page is redirected to the new location. Both actions should normally fire with one click.

Comment: What if you wrap it in a `$timeout(function() { $location.path('/login.signin'); }, 0);`?  Don't forget to inject `$timeout`.

Comment: I just noticed you're using firebase - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296778/location-path-not-working-first-time-with-ionic-firebase

Comment: @Zach can you suggest which part i should change? I can't figure out the response from the other question.

Comment: Here's another useful blog: https://blog.khophi.co/redirect-requested-page-login-firebase-auth/

Comment: Would you please list your ui-router states on here? I would like to check the order of them.  They need to be in a specific order (from most specific to general) or this scenario can  result.

Comment: @Zach i added a link to the router config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that question - it looks like the significant change was using `$state.go('profile', _user )`, which is part of ui-router, instead of `$location.path`, but since this is a third-party library - it's possible it's being called outside of angular's digest. I would try the following, assuming you're using ui-router: replace your call with `$state.go('login.signin')`.

```
$scope.resetMe = function () {
    var newPassword = $scope.user.password;
    var actionCode = $location.search().oobCode;
    var mode = $location.search().mode;
    firebase.auth().confirmPasswordReset(actionCode, newPassword)
        .then(function (resp) {
        console.log("reset pass, done");
        $location.path('/signin').replace(); // Add this
        $state.go('login.signin'); // and this
    }).catch(function (error) {
        $scope.errMsg = true;
        $scope.errorMessage = error.message;
    });
}
```

The other significant change in that post was that they had the call to firebase wrapped in a service and they returned the promise back to the call in the controller.

```
app.factory("AuthenticationService", ["firebase", function (firebase) {
// Inside your service
   return {
      resetPassword: function(actionCode, newPassword) {
         // return this next line
         return firebase.auth().confirmPasswordReset(actionCode, newPassword)
              .then(function (resp) {
              console.log("reset pass, done");
              return resp; // return the response
          });
      }
   }
}]);
```

and inside your controller:

```
$scope.resetMe = function () {
    var newPassword = $scope.user.password;
    var actionCode = $location.search().oobCode;
    var mode = $location.search().mode;
    AuthenticationService.resetPassword(actionCode, newPassword)
    .then(function (resp) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
           $location.path('/signin').replace();
           $state.go('login.signin');
        });
    }).catch(function (error) {
        $scope.errMsg = true;
        $scope.errorMessage = error.message;
    });
}
```

Comment: i implemented these, but the same happens again. I need to click again to be redirected. By the way, I see the console message saying that reset is done.

Comment: At this point, I would say you need to look into whether or not the event is firing for the state change.  Do you have a listener for `$on('$stateChangeStart')`?

Comment: no i don't have this! where should it be? can you give an example please?

Comment: A small thing I noticed... your url for `login.signin` state is `/signin` so your `$location.path` should have been `$location.path('/signin')`.  Don't know if it'll change anything but give it a shot.

Comment: it doesn't change anything though. it is still the same.
actually, in my registration controller, when I sign up, it redirects to the new location. http://pastebin.com/CXvqNKxm 
and I am using the same location referer.

Comment: Ok.  Let's make sure that this is firing during a `$digest`.  Please wrap the `$state.go()` in a `$scope.$apply(function() { });` function as I have in the updated code above.  If you get an error about it already being in a $digest, then we'll try something else.